# Parsing html page by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have to get a value from ajax response (html).
Below is my ajax call,

```
var result = $.ajax({
                //datatype : "application/json",
                type: "POST",
                url: ddcUrl,
                data: {Bin:cardNumber, JWT:encodedJWT},
                complete: function(event){
                    console.log(event);
                }
            });
```

And below is my response (in HTML format)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cardinal DDC Sim</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>

    sendNotification(true, "28eb7c91-699c-4115-b25e-1ba2dc513e3e");

    function sendNotification(status, sessionId){
        try{
            var message = {
                MessageType: 'profile.completed',
                SessionId: sessionId,
                Status: status
            };
            window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message), '*');
        } catch(error){
            console.error('Failed to notify parent', error)
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to get the value **28eb7c91-699c-4115-b25e-1ba2dc513e3e** in inside of javascript function.

The request supposed to be happened in iframe so that response (session id inside) will be added in window parameter by using below function some thing like,

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {  

       var data = JSON.parse(event.data);

       if (data !== undefined && data.Status) {
           // Extract the value of `SessionId` for onward processing.
       }

}, false);
```

But because of some other issue I'm sending request by using ajax.

Since the value defined in inside javascript function I'm not able to fetch that session id parameter. i.e. **28eb7c91-699c-4115-b25e-1ba2dc513e3e.** Is there any solution to get this ?

Comment: If all you want is the session id string you would need to use regex to get it out of the html string. Or change server side response

Answer (score 0):

basic regular expression should be able to match the pattern from the text.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: ddcUrl,
  data: {Bin:cardNumber, JWT:encodedJWT},
  dataType: "text",
})
.done(function( data ) {
   var code = data.match(/sendNotification\(true, "([a-f0-9\-]+)"\)/)
   console.log(code);
});
```